# Jquery button click to select check box

Tags: jquery

I have grid with user data with first column having check box. I have a button at the top of the grid. If I click button I need to select top 5 users from the list.

Can anybody tell me how to do this using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#Grid input[type=checkbox]:lt(5)').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

If you have other checkboxes in the grid, there may be in issue. This is the best I can do without seeing your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead.

Base on the accepted answer you can do this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $("#Grid input[type=checkbox]").slice(0,5).attr('checked','checked');
});
```